# Android market incompatible

Tags: android, manifest, google-play, incompatibility

I have published my app on android market. I was able to download it to my phone(samsung galaxy sl [i9003]) but, recently I updated my phone through kies to 2.3.6 from 2.3.5 and now market is saying your app is incompatible with my device. What should I do to make it compatible ?

My phone is rooted and have market version 3.3.12 . Do I need to change any properties of app in manifest ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="XXX"
  android:versionName="1.1.1" android:versionCode="7">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="false"></supports-screens>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="false" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="MenuActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.inmobi.androidsdk.IMBrowserActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" />
    <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name=".BrowseMovies"></activity> 
    <activity android:name="SongDisplayDetails" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    <activity android:name="SearchDataActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>                
</application>
```

Comment: What features are you requiring in your app?

Comment: @rohit please paste your manifest into your post. It is possible that there is an error in the manifest file that prevents your app from being downloaded on your phone.

Comment: @janusz- added manifest pls check and reply

Comment: i thought the problem is not with manifest coz i m able to download when i have 2.3.5 but unable when 2.3.6

Answer (score 0):

There is options in market console: when you publish your app, in section "publish params" there is list of all known devices, and there you can see all incompatible devices, and reason why they are incompatible.

// I'm not sure in names of sections in market case I have Russian version of market console. Section "publish params" goes just before "Contacts"

Answer (score 0):

1. Find out which devices are incompatible by clicking the "compatible devices see List" in Developer Console when you are able to "Upload APK".
   This lists all those it will install on and also those it won't. For me this was teh Key step, find out which ones and whats "wrong" with them.
2. In my case the use of the phone was optional. It had the uses-permission for phones and recording for example which might not be needed. Some use cases need these, some don't.`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

This was what was causing it to exclude all my tablets.

```
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

This seems to have solved it, there are now no incompatible devices in the  Play.Store.
Now I just need people to download and use it!